# Max size of envelope in request.addproperty for ksoap2

Tags: android, ksoap2

I need help with the following error when trying to upload a base64 encoded image using ksoap2

org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4101e708)

It works fine when i try to upload a small image or even works fine when i try to upload 1MB image.

Following is the scenario:
I have created packet folder inside my assets folder. I use following code to access my image:

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
            // am.open("packet/sky.png", MODE_PRIVATE);
            InputStream is = am.open("packet/sky.png", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

If i place my image in res folder and write :

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.sky);
```

It works fine, but does not when i try to do it with AssetManager.

i have following code for ksoap call

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("xml", param);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        transportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

I get XMLPullParserException.

Is there any size limit for ksoap2 request?

Comment: Problem is not your request. Problem is server limit. I had same problem with a .NET webservice for uploading photos. After somedays i found the problem. Server had a limit in upload size. I removed it and everything works fine. By the way, the only limit in ksoap request and response is device memory free in that moment. You have to consider that all request or response is saved entirely in memory. So, if memory (HeapSize) dedicated for application is small or there is only a little free portion, OutOfMemory exception will occur

Comment: @kinghomer: thanks for the reply. I tested the soap request/response here: http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html. And it works fine. Issue arises only when i try to make a call from android app. I am using android version 2.3.3 haven't tested it in later versions as i do not have to support it.